# Unable to start spark thriftserver (hive-site.xml for spark didn't overwrite default value)

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hive, metastore

Backgroud:

1. CentOS7
2. hadoop-2.7.3
3. spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
4. apache-hive-2.1.0-bin (only used to start metastore service by hive --service metastore)
5. Have HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME and HIVE_HOME etc. configured
6. mysql 5.7.16
7. Have put mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar into both hive/lib/ and spark/jars/

hive-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://www.test.com:3306/metastore</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hive</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>password</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://www.test.com:9083</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I put hive-site.xml into both hive/conf/ and spark/conf/

But run start-thriftserver.sh, I got error logs (in spark_home/logs/spark-*-HiveThriftServer2*.out):

```
......
INFO HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://www.test.com:9083
INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
......
DEBUG ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL value null from  jpox.properties with jdbc:derby:memory:;databaseName=/tmp/spark-37dcab7f-655a-4506-abd7-492a8620a33e/metastore;create=true
......
INFO MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
......
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

In log we can see property "hive.metastore.uris" did work.

But seems other mysql relative properties didn't work, metastore still use the default database derby.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Resolved:

I Removed hive.metastore.uris because I just used hive locally.

```html
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://www.test.com:9083</value>
</property>
```

Set hive.metasotre.schema.verification to false. Thanks for Nirmal's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this error log

```
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore
```

set,
value of
`hive.metastore.schema.verification` to false in hive-site.xml in both hive and spark conf and restart services and try again

Comment: Nirmal, thanks for ur help, I tired like you said, but still the same error.
I think these properties have default set even without list them in hive-site.xml.

Comment: Nirmal, I don't get hive-metastore.log. I just get log after running spark_home/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh in spark_home/logs.
And can get hive.log after running hive cli in /tmp/{user}/. I just edit my question, please check.

Comment: can you share me the full logs from spark_home//logs

Comment: check this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15118  metastore might be using mysql

Comment: Nirmal, added full log by my own reply. Thanks for help again.

Comment: can you go to hive prompt and run any query there? is it working

Comment: Nirmal, thanks very much! It's works! hive.metastore.schema.verification always need to be set to false, otherwise it will report this error.

Comment: welcome @Furyegg You may accept this as Answer/upvote. Can be helpful to others